# How to select entire row on clicking the row header?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik, radgridview

I want to have ability select cells and select rows.
For selecting cells I've set SelectionUnit="Cells" and SelectionMode="Extended".
It works fine. But now I need in ability to select rows. It's clear for user to select rows via rows headers (at the left part of row).

How to implement it easily?

Comment: this is component specific behavior, I think you'll have more luck checking on the forums of telerik.

Comment: can you be more elaborate on your question? Confused with your statement of Row Header ? Please give more details so that i can better understand your problem.

Comment: I've changed problem description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick fix:

```
private void RadGridView_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        return;

    var source = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
    if(source == null)
        return;

    var cell = source.FindVisualParent<GridViewCell>();
    if(cell != null)
    {
        ((RadGridView)sender).SelectionUnit = GridViewSelectionUnit.Cell;
    }
    else
    {
        var row = source.FindVisualParent<GridViewRow>();
        if(row != null)
        {
            ((RadGridView)sender).SelectionUnit = GridViewSelectionUnit.FullRow;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The RadGridView out of the box will provide you the feature to set the selection units to either Cells or FullRow only. It cannot provide you with both conditions.

You are able to provide extended cell selection by setting the SelectionUnit to Cell and SelectionMode to Extened.

Now in order to make the row selection you will have to change the SelectionUnit to FullRow.

This is how the RadGridView works.

For more information documentation i suggest you to have a look at the following documentation on this feature:

http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/gridview-selection-basics.html

http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/gridview-multiple-selection.html

Comment: May be do you know any workarounds for enabling both conditions?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've found solution how to bypass this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Just add telerik gridviewselectcolumn when you define your columns. This column adds checkbox to each rows and header. By Clicking on the header checkbox will select all rows.

```
<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
 <telerik:GridViewSelectColumn HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyle1}"/>
 <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Column1" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyle1}" MinWidth="150"
                                                    DataMemberBinding="{Binding XYZ}" />
</telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
```